# Bootstrap glyphicon edit not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to implement bootstrap glyphicon edit but its not showing in my web page though its showing in [bootply](http://bootply.com/94661) Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/rBVB6/) I have included all the necessary `js` and `css`.This is the code 
From the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)
to show edit glyphicon `<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="edit"></a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using bootstrap 2.2 so the icon prefixes are `icon-*` not `glyphicon-*`

```
<a class="icon icon-search" id="edit"></a>
```

*In bootstrap 3.* the prefix got changed to `glyphicon-*`*

Comment: Well how do you come to know that i am using 2.2 not 3?

Comment: because he used 2.2 in earlier days.. so he know it very well and he is the one of  the good guy in SO for helping others :)

Comment: @javaBeginner, your fiddle loads bootstrap 2.2.2 -- so not much magic there ;-)